# Java Wait for thread to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, download, wait

I have a thread downloading data and I want to wait until the download is finished before I load the data.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

More Info:

I have a Download class that gets data from a URL (Serialized POJOs).  Download is Runnable and Observable.  It keeps track of the bytes downloaded and download size.  I have a progress bar that displays the progress to the User.   The GUI observes Download to update the progress bar.

When the POJO is downloaded I want to get it and move to the next step.  Each step has to wait for the previous to finish.  The problem is I cant think of a way to pause my application to wait for the download thread.  Once the download is finished I want to call `download.getObject()` which will return the data as an object.  I can then cast it and get on with the next download.

I have a helper class that manages the URLs for download and makes all of the calls to Download.  This call will call getObject and do the casting.  The Gui calls `helper.getUser()`. helper starts the thread running and I want it to 'know' when it is finished so it can return the casted object.

Any suggestions/examples? I am in the beginning stages of this design so I am willing to change it.

**Update:**

I followed [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) and used modal to block until the thread finished.  The code was very messy and I don't like this approach.  I will keep trying to find a 'clean' way to handle the workflow of the download processes.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`Thread` has a method that does that for you [join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) which will block until the thread has finished executing.

Comment: I tried join() but that kept the GUI from updating.  The reason I used a Thread was to keep the gui updating while the download was occurring.  Calling join stops that from happening.

Comment: join() will work. if the GUI stops updating, you probably have to be more detailed about which threads you are joining. I wouldn't join the EDT.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you are not calling `join()` in the swing thread. You can do this by creating one thread that is in charge of your download thread. This is essentially just a background worker that you can forget about. It is the worker thread that knows when the download finishes and what to do at that point. You just need to make sure edits to the swing objects are done in the swing thread.

Comment: `join()` doesn't rethrow exceptions thrown inside the thread. So after `join()` has released current thread you don't know whether the thread finished successfully or not.

Answer (score 79):

You could use a `CountDownLatch` from the `java.util.concurrent` package. It is very useful when waiting for one or more threads to complete before continuing execution in the awaiting thread.

For example, waiting for three tasks to complete:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
...
latch.await(); // Wait for countdown
```

The other thread(s) then each call `latch.countDown()` when complete with the their tasks. Once the countdown is complete, three in this example, the execution will continue.

Comment: Works perfect for apps without GUI.

Comment: I'd like to add this is a very flexible solution and doesn't necessarily have to be for awaiting all threads. You can set the latch to `new CountDownLatch(1)` if you only want to wait for the _first_ thread to complete. This is the best answer for handling more than two concurrent threads.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. The easiest solution in the question for non-GUI apps.

Answer (score 18):

Better alternatives to [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) method have been evolved over a period of time.

[ExecutorService.html#invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) is one alternative.

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list.

Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

[ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) or [Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--) provides other alternatives to achieve the same purpose.

Example code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import java.util.*;

public class InvokeAllDemo{
    public InvokeAllDemo(){
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        List<MyCallable> futureList = new ArrayList<MyCallable>();
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i);
            futureList.add(myCallable);
        }
        System.out.println("Start");
        try{
            List<Future<Long>> futures = service.invokeAll(futureList);  
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        InvokeAllDemo demo = new InvokeAllDemo();
    }
    class MyCallable implements Callable<Long>{
        Long id = 0L;
        public MyCallable(Long val){
            this.id = val;
        }
        public Long call(){
            // Add your business logic
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly: all `Callable`s will be executed in parallel, not subsequently?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `join()` to wait for all threads to finish. Like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(i));                
    T1.start();   
    try {             
       T1.join(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

[SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) has `doInBackground()` which you can use to perform a task. You have the option to invoke `get()` and wait for the download to complete or you can override the `done()` method which will be invoked on the event dispatch thread once the SwingWorker completes.

The Swingworker has advantages to your current approach in that it has many of the features you are looking for so there is no need to reinvent the wheel. You are able to use the `getProgress()` and `setProgress()` methods as an alternative to an observer on the runnable for download progress.  The `done()` method as I stated above is called after the worker finishes executing and is performed on the EDT, this allows you load the data after the download has completed.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine that you're calling your download in a background thread such as provided by a SwingWorker. If so, then simply call your next code sequentially in the same SwingWorker's doInBackground method.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when you want to wait for a thread to finish, you should call [join()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions/examples? I followed [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)... The code was very messy and I don't like this approach.

Instead of `get()`, which waits for completion, use `process()` and `setProgress()` to show intermediate results, as suggested in this simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725) or this related [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).

Answer (score 0):

The [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another.However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as long as you specify.