# Why FixedThreadPool not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Here's my following code:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              System.out.println("Start"+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
              try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              System.out.println("End!"+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    });

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here's my output:

```
    Start  pool-1-thread-1
    End!  pool-1-thread-1
    Start  pool-1-thread-1
    End!  pool-1-thread-1
    Start  pool-1-thread-1
    End!  pool-1-thread-1
    Start  pool-1-thread-1
    End!  pool-1-thread-1
    Start  pool-1-thread-1
    End!  pool-1-thread-1
```

My understanding is that in my code there're `5` threads in `FixedThreadPool`. So when I run my code, it's supposed to output all  `5` threads, right? Or Am I misunderstanding something?

In my output `thread-1` starts and end everytime but isn't it supposed to output all `5` threads when it loops in `for` loop?
Cause if only 1`thread` is doing the `task` then why do we even need 5 `threads`?
Is there any way all `5` threads can output on the console?(I'm a newbie)

Comment: You've submitted one task. Why do you expect it to be run on 5 threads?

Comment: I'm a newbie and yea I got it now.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting only one `Runnable` so your `ExecutorService` runs one task. It will use only one thread. To use multiple threads you must call `submit` multiple times or you can call `invokeAll` with a `Collection` of runnables.

***EDIT***

Something like this:

```
public void test() {
    int numberOfThreads = 5;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++){
        executorService.submit(createRunnable());
    }
}

private Runnable createRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Start" + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("End!" + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it. But can you please provide me some code for `invokeAll`. I don't know how to do it with `invokeAll`. It will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly want? 5 threads, each of them printing out a start and an end message? Or 5 thread each having a 5 iteration loop, so each thread would print 5 start and 5 end messages?

Comment: I want each thread having a 5 iteration loop, so each thread would print 5 start and 5 end messages.

Comment: Okay, I've added an example

Comment: But you said we can even do it with `invokeAll`. So how I can do with `invokeAll`.I don't want the whole code. I understand that `execute.invokeAll()` is all I've to do but what should I write inside `invokeAll()` parameters.

Comment: Ah yes it needs `Callable` instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: Can't we use `invokeAll` with `Runnable`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However Callables are like runnables, just having a return value which can be used later on in `Future` objects, which can be useful.

Comment: Have you figured it out how to use `Callable`-s? I cam give an example about it in chat

Comment: Yes, I've used `Callable`-s before.

Comment: You mean I should move this conversation into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124664/discussion-between-hemlata-and-abbath).

Comment: @Hemalata - Refer to this question for invokeAll usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691533/java-wait-for-thread-to-finish/39476747#39476747