# Java Thread And Exception Handling

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have a method as below:

```
// Main Class:
processRecords(ArrayList<String> records) {
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    ProcessRecordThread thread = new ProcessRecordThread(records);
    new Thread(thread).start();
    return isSuccess;
}    

// Thread class:

run() {
    for (String record : records) {
        try {
            process(record);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isSuccess = false;
        } 
    }
}
```

I want my main class to wait for my thread to complete processing of all records and then return `isSuccess` variable and continue with main class execution.

Comment: If you want to wait until everything is complete, why do it in a separate thread at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Wait for thread to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691533/java-wait-for-thread-to-finish)

Comment: Note: It looks like `ProcessRecordThread` is not a Thread, but an implementation of Runnable. Maybe it should be called `RecordProcessor`? or `RecordProcessRunnable`?

Why do you want to run this process in a single separate Thread and wait for its completion in the calling thread? This would only be beneficial if either the calling thread starts multiple threads that do parallel processing, or the calling thread does not wait for the  processing to complete (asynchronous processing).

Comment: @AdriaanKoster i have created a new thread because my each record in my list contain multiple records within itself.the process function inside my function is async function.

Comment: Did you consider using `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`?

Comment: Looping all records in parallel is as simple as `records.parallelStream().forEach(ProcessRecordThread::process)` or sth. like that