# Is it OK that child thread terminated when main thread exit in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Given a file looks like below:

```
Thread.new {
  (1..10).each do |e| 
    `curl http://localhost/#{e}`
  end 
}

sleep 0.03
puts "--- done"
```

When running this file, I found the "child thread" exits when it only sent 4-5 HTTP requests.

My question is: is this because the "ruby intepreter" exited? (so all the ruby threads terminated?)

How could I keep the "child thread" running when the "main thread" terminated?

If I run this code in ruby webservers such as thin, puma, does this problem exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the main thread exits, the process terminates and it stops all the other running threads. To avoid that, you can call [`Thread#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html#method-i-join) that waits for the other thread.

```
thread = Thread.new {
  (1..10).each do |e| 
    `curl http://localhost/#{e}`
  end 
}

thread.join
```

Webservers processes most probably won't exit, but they may finish serving a request before the thread ends fetching the URL. It may be better to use a [background processing tool](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs) to handle that case.

Comment: In other language such as Java/PHP,  do they act like Ruby? ( child thread terminated when the main thread exits )

Comment: Yes, I believe it's the default behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875956/when-the-main-thread-exits-do-other-threads-also-exit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691533/java-wait-for-thread-to-finish. You need to call `join` to wait for a thread.

Comment: yeah, sure!  I found it seems that in Java, "child thread" will run when main thread terminates. in C/C++, it acts the same with Ruby.  I am not sure. so I will give enough test when I have time.  thank you very much!