# MultiThreading in Java not Working as Expected

Tags: java, multithreading

The first code does not always show the sum to be 1000, so I figured a way around to fix the problem but why does not the first code work? The results are highly inconsistent and I know that using synchronized does not serve any purpose in this case, but I was just trying.

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{
    int[] count;
    int[] event;
    Thread1(int[] event, int[] count){
        this.event=event;
        this.count=count;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<500; i++){

            int x = event[i];
            synchronized (count){
                count[x]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread{
    int[] count;
    int[] event;
    Thread2(int[] event, int[] count){
        this.event=event;
        this.count=count;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=500; i<1000; i++){

            int x = event[i];
            synchronized (count){
                count[x]++;
            }

        }
    }
}

public class Learning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] event = new int[1000];

        for(int i=0; i<event.length; i++){
            event[i] = random.nextInt(3);
        }

        Thread1 a = new Thread1(event, new int[3]);
        Thread2 b = new Thread2(event, new int[3]);

        a.start();
        b.start();

        int second = a.count[1]+b.count[1];
        int third = a.count[2]+b.count[2];
        int first = a.count[0]+b.count[0];

        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);
        System.out.println(third);

        System.out.println("SUM--> "+(first+second+third));
    }
}
```

**WORKS HERE:** 
[image]

**DOES NOT WORK HERE**
[image]

The code sometimes shows a total of 1000 entries, sometimes doesn't. I don't feel there is any need to synchronize as no common resource is being accesed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add all relevant information directly to your post and avoid screenshots. You might want to check [ask] as well.

Comment: I don't see the point of the screenshots.  I also don't see the point of posting two copies of 100+ lines of code that are virtually identical ... without explaining how they differ.

Comment: Have you tried to join your threads? After `a.start()` and `b.start()` you could add a `a.join()` and a `b.join()` to make sure that they both terminate before you calculate the `sum`

Comment: What is the difference between the first code and the second code? It looks like a pretty standard race condition where first, second and third are being created using values that change depending on whether both threads have finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread1` and `Thread2` classes use their respective `count` objects to synchronize.

The problem is that you instantiate them like this:

```
    Thread1 a = new Thread1(event, new int[3]);
    Thread2 b = new Thread2(event, new int[3]);
```

See?

You are passing **different** arrays to the two threads.  If your two threads use different objects as their `count`, you do not get mutual exclusion or proper memory visibility.

---

On further examination, it looks like the synchronized block is probably unnecessary anyway.  (You don't need mutual exclusion, and you get certain guarantees that the child threads will see properly initialized arrays because of the `start()` *happens-before*.)

However, it is clear that it is necessary to `join` the two child threads in the main thread for a couple of reasons:

1. If you don't `join()`, you cannot be sure that the child threads have completed before the main thread looks at the results.
2. If you don't `join()`, there are potential memory anomalies ... *even if the child threads have both terminated* before the main thread looks at the counts.  (The `join()` call imposes a *happens-before* relationship between the child threads and the main thread.)

---

Your attempted solution using `stop()` is bogus for the following reasons:

1. The `stop()` method is deprecated because it is dangerous.  It shouldn't be used.
2. The `stop()` method doesn't have a specified synchronizing effect.
3. Based on the documented semantics (such as they are) there is no logical reason that calling `stop()` should fix the problem.

As a general rule "randomly trying thing" is not a sound strategy for fixing concurrency bugs.  There is a good chance that a random chance will not fix a bug, but turn it from a bug that occurs frequently to one that occurs rarely ... or only on a different Java platform to the one you test on.

Why does it appear to work?

It looks like the child threads terminated before they stopped.  But it is just luck that that is happening.  It is unlikely to happen if you scale up the amount of work that the child threads do.

Comment: I think the idea is that the sum of `count[0]` from Thread1 and `count[0]` from Thread2 is the number of all `0`s in `event` : `int first = a.count[0]+b.count[0];` So OP is right that the sum of all 0s, all 1s and all 2s should be `1000`.. unless the threads don't terminate properly? But again, I am not sure I understand the problem

Comment: If you are correct, the bad synchronization is >>the<< problem.

Comment: Is there even a need to synchronize? Thread1 handles the first 500 entries of 'event', sees the values and increments in the count. Similarly, Thread2 handles the next 500 entries of 'event' and it increments in count array. At last, I am trying to add both the count arrays.

Comment: @StephenC the other issue is not `join`ing.

Comment: adding - a.stop(); b.stop(); after a.start(); b.start(); fixes the problem. Any explanation?

Comment: 1) It is a random non-fix.  It is easy to make a multi-threaded program *seem* to work by making changes that are unrelated to the real bug or bugs. 2) Don't call `Thread.stop()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

adding - a.stop(); b.stop(); after a.start(); b.start(); fixes the problem.

But I don't understand why.

Comment: because when you reach the line where it executes `a.stop()` and `b.stop()` it is most likely finished with the execution. Though as Stephen C already mentioned, this is random. Imagine your thread `a` would take 10 seconds to complete - but you already reach the line `a.stop()` after 1 second - then it will force it to stop and it would have completed only 10%. So: it is not a solution, it is random. [You need to wait for the threads to terminate on their own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691544/896249)