# Java Multithreading - how to use wait() and notify() to get a value from only 1 thread out of 2 and kill the other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

In my main thread I create two additional threads that I want to use a value from. Basically what I want to do is this:

```
Threads thread1 = new Threads();
Threads thread2 = new Threads();
Thread.currentThread.wait();
If (thread1 = complete){
var = thread1.getter
//delete thread2
}
If (thread2 == complete){
var = thread2.getter
//delete thread1
}
```

With thread1 and thread2 having a notify() at the end that wakes up the main thread and the thread that doesn't finish is deleted. But I realise that I don't properly understand wait() and multithreading so the way this is setup may not be correct. I know that Thread.currentThread.wait() is definitely not correct.

I think I may have to synchronize the methods but I have not been able to find any examples that show how to do this in this situation.

Edit: To give more info Thread1 takes input from a scanner and Thread2 takes input from a keylistener and I want to use the first input from 1 of them

Comment: wait and notify and fairly low level operations that act as the basis for some other concurrency primitives. IMO you as an application developer should almost never be using them directly.

Comment: Re, `Thread.currentThread.wait()`, The [javadoc for Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) says, "It is recommended that applications _not_ use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are saying that your threads are *racing* to solve a problem, and you are only interested in whichever solution is produced *first.* Am I right?  If so, then what you need is some shared variables that allow all the threads to know if a solution has been found:

```java
boolean solution_is_found = false;
SolutionType solution;
final Object solution_mutex = new Object();
```

A worker thread can do this:

```java
while (true) {
    synchronized(solution_mutex) {
        if (solution_is_found) {
            // Some other thread won the race, our solution is not needed.
            return;
        }
    }
    ...do some increment of work...
    if (...this thread found a solution...) {
        synchronized(solution_mutex) {
            if (! solution_was_found) {
                // Only update the variables if this thread won the race.
                solution_is_found = true;
                solution = ...what this thread found...
                solution_mutex.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

And now, the main thread can await the appearance of the first solution.

```java
synchronized(solution_lock) {
    while (! solution_was_found) {
        solution_lock.wait();
    }
}

...use `solution` here...
```

---

If the smallest possible "increment of work" takes a significant chunk of time, then you may want to test `solution_is_found` several times within the "increment," and abort if it is `true`.

Comment: Exactly right, I only care about whichever value was calculated first. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `wait` and `notify` in your case. Just use `join` to wait until the thread is completed.

More info: [Java Wait for thread to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691533/java-wait-for-thread-to-finish)

Comment: I think OP wants to wait for whichever thread finishes _first,_ and then tell the other threads to give up. There is no `join()` method that awaits more than one thread.